# Sort Selection Method giving ArrayOutofBounds

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create array

    int[] array = {99,45,1,51,11,71,22,33,44,55,32,64,88,76,89};

    System.out.println("Before calling Selection Sort");
    for(int i = 0; i<= array.length-1; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i]+ " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    selectionSort(array); //LINE 14

    System.out.println("After calling Selection Sort");
    for(int i=0; i<=array.length-1; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i]+ " ");
    }
}
public static void selectionSort(int[] array) {
    //finding minimum
    int min=0;

    for(int i=0; i<=array.length-1; i++) {
        min = i;
        for(int j = i+1; i<array.length-1; j++) {
            if(array[j]>array[min]) { //LINE 28
                min = j;
        }
    }
        //swapping
        if(array[i]>min) {
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[min];
        array[min] = temp;
}
```

I'm getting:
ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException: 15, 
Error in line 28, 
Error in line 14. Those problems are solved. Now, the numbers aren't swapping properly. They are not in ascending order. Help please!

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<=array.length-1; i++) {` - You're iterating until the last element and then calling `array[i + 1]`, which is out of bounds.

Answer (score 2):

In this part of code :

`for(int j = i+1; i<array.length-1; j++) {
     if(array[j]>array[min]) { //LINE 28
         min = j;
}`

You call `array[j]` where `j = i + 1` or `i` is the last element of the array at the end of the iteration so `array[i+1]` is out of bounds.

Furthermore :

`for(int j = i+1; i<array.length-1; j++)`

must be changed by

`for(int j = i+1; j<array.length-1; j++)`

Here the version where the output is correct :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //create array

    int[] array = {99,45,1,51,11,71,22,33,44,55,32,64,88,76,89};

    System.out.println("Before calling Selection Sort");
    for(int i = 0; i<= array.length-1; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i]+ " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    selectionSort(array); //LINE 14

    System.out.println("After calling Selection Sort");
    for(int i=0; i<=array.length-1; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i]+ " ");
    }
}

public static void selectionSort(int[] array) {
    //finding minimum
    int min=0;

    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        min = i;
        for(int j = i+1; j<array.length; j++) {
            if(array[j]<array[min]) { //LINE 28
                min = j;
            }
        }

        //swapping
        if(array[i]>min) {
                int temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[min];
                array[min] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I just noticed that it was an "i" instead of "j". I should start using a different inner loop variable to avoid this problem in the future. Now I'm facing another problem: it's not swapping the numbers properly. They are not in ascending order.

Comment: At line 28 the condition was wrong, check the edit of my post ;)

Comment: I also change the condition in your for line 27 :

for(int j = i+1; i<array.length-1; j++) {

become

for(int j = i+1; j<array.length; j++) {

Answer (score 0):

the problem is `(int j = i+1; i<array.length-1; j++)`   make an ou of bounds exception u should use `j<array.length` instead . try this

```
for(int i=0; i<=array.length-1; i++) {
        min = i;
        for(int j = i+1; j<array.length-1; j++) {
            if(array[j]>array[min]) { //LINE 28
                min = j;
        }
```